# jekyll with broken front matter, how to find the broken file?

Tags: github, jekyll

When I make a syntax error in the front matter i'm getting the following error:

```
 /.../psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected
 ':' while scanning a simple key at line 6 column 1
 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from /.../psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
        from /.../psych.rb:151:in `parse'
            from ....
```

Do you know a way to tell what file caused the problem?

I know that I could probably use DTrace as follows:

```
dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry { printf("%s %s",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'| grep _posts
```

But I'm looking for something more straight forward.

Comment: What version of jekyll are you useing? In 0.11.0 I get something like `YAML Exception reading 2012-04-29-a-new-post.md: syntax error on line 3, col -1: ` if I have bad YAML.

Comment: @Alan, I use the same version of jekyll however, but probably the problem lays in ruby's new yaml parser I use 1.9.3. Thank you for help.

Comment: I had this problem, then I realized that my database.yml file was not strictly correct. (I left out a space after a ':') I fixed that and I got past that error.

Comment: @Vineel right on, same thing adding space after ':' fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seams that jekyll does not work well on ruby 1.9.3. A more restrictive yaml parser was introduced: Psych that probably has different exception hierarchy and there for it is not properly handled by jekyll.

Answer (score 3):

**You may find that this is caused by faulty formatting**

If your front matter looks like this:

```
---
menu:
- text: Home
url: /en/index.html
- text: Overview
url: /en/overview.html
---
```

instead of

```
---
menu:
- text: Home
  url: /en/index.html
- text: Overview
  url: /en/overview.html
---
```

then the YAML parser will throw it out.

Comment: Yes in my case it the yml file was loading in environment.rb. Thus I was getting this error. Solved by correcting yml file.