# Error whilst starting rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and the bundle install works fine for the project. but when I start the rails server errors are shown.The shown errors are attached herewith.

```
 Exiting
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find e
xpected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 27 column 3 (Psych::SyntaxError)

        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from D:/ROR/appmallserver/config/environment.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'    
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from D:/ROR/appmallserver/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from D:/ROR/appmallserver/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from D:/ROR/appmallserver/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:21:in `require'
        from script/rails:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please check your database.yml file once in config folder carefully.

Comment: what should i be checking for can you please be little more specific.as i said am new to ROR.

Comment: development:
  adapter: your_database_adopter
  encoding: utf8
  database: blog_your_database_name
  pool: 5
  username: your_username
  password: your_password
  host: localhost

Comment: Once you go through the below url <br />
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417122/jekyll-with-broken-front-matter-how-to-find-the-broken-file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417122/jekyll-with-broken-front-matter-how-to-find-the-broken-file

Answer (score 0):

Once you please go through the below url 
[jekyll with broken front matter, how to find the broken file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417122/jekyll-with-broken-front-matter-how-to-find-the-broken-file)

That will help you.